# Is there way to to return the group only if the group is the exact length specified?

Tags: c#, regex

The following regex

```
(\d{3,4})
```

matches `1234` in

`123456`, but since `123456` is longer than 4, I don't want the regex to match anything.

These are my 3 regular expressions that I am using separately, I tried combining them, but it returns more than 2 groups and I just need 2 at the most.

```
//Match card number before security code
(?<!\d)(\d{13,16})(?!\d)[<""'].*?(?=[>""']\d{3,4}[<""'])[>""'](?<!\d)(\d{3,4})(?!\d)[<""']

//Match card number after security code
(?<!\d)(\d{3,4})(?!\d)[<""'].*?(?=[>""']\d{13,16}[<""'])[>""'](?<!\d)(\d{13,16})(?!\d)[<""']

//Match just card number
(?<!\d)(\d{13,16})(?!\d)
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yup

```
(?<!\d)(\d{3,4})(?!\d)
```

should do the trick. Since the `?<!` and `?!` assertions are *zero-width*, they don't actually match anything (they just check the parse state against the input at the current position). So you could just as well say

```
((?<!\d)\d{3,4}(?!\d))
```

if you preferred.

---

See http://www.regular-expressions.info/refadv.html

> `(?!regex)`
>
> > Zero-width negative lookahead. Identical to positive lookahead, except that the overall match will only succeed if the regex inside the lookahead fails to match.

Comment: This confused me at first, but then I got it. Basically your looking back and forward to make sure no digits exist, right?

Comment: My original regex is more complex, but I can't figure out how to only return 2 groups even if I have 6 specified in my expression.  I basically want to do an OR on the groups

Comment: @Xaisoft: please explain your actual problem. What do you mean by "groups"?

Comment: @Xaisoft it would help if you updated the question describing what the 'groups' are and what you mean by `do an OR on the groups`. Regardless, does `(\d{4}|\d{3})` help? Perhaps even repeatedly and asserting no adjacent digits: `(?<!\d)(\d{4}|\d{3})+(?!\d)` ?

Comment: @sehe - I have a question already, but haven't got much help. Right now I am using three reqular expressions.  Here is the link:  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9039998/combine-a-positive-lookahead-and-negative-lookahead/9041049#comment11342953_9041049

Answer (score 1):

Use \b to mark the beginning and end of the string, a la

\b\d{3,4}\b

Comment: But it gets a little hairy if valid is `aaa1234bbbb`

Comment: This answer is nice and simple and would work in my case, but as sehe pointed out, has the flaw.

Answer (score 0):

Try this: `(\b\d{3,4}\b)`  The `\b` character means word boundary.  if you just want any non-digit characters, try `\D(\d{3,4})\D`

Comment: Like eouw...'s answer: not ok for valid input like `aaa1234bbbb`