# iterate through all nodes of an xml file

Tags: xml, vb.net

```
<ArrayOfContacts xmlns:i="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns="someschema">
 <Contact>
    <ID />
    <First_Name />
    <Last_Name />
    <TelephoneNumbers>
        <TelephoneNumber>
            <Number />
            <IsHome />
            <IsWork />
            <IsCell />
            <ReachableAfterHrs />
        </TelephoneNumber>
    </TelephoneNumbers>
 </Contact>
  <Contact>
    <ID />
    <First_Name />
    <Last_Name />
    <TelephoneNumbers>
        <TelephoneNumber>
            <Number />
            <IsHome />
            <IsWork />
            <IsCell />
            <ReachableAfterHrs />
        </TelephoneNumber>
    </TelephoneNumbers>
 </Contact>
</ArrayOfContacts>
```

Looked at [this article](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2915294/iterating-through-all-nodes-in-xml-file). Looking for a good way to go over the entire xml and change all node values that need to be changed, this would be dynamically chosen and then to save the document

My recursive routine is similar to [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1596163/traverse-a-xml-using-recursive-function)

however when it encounters `<TelephoneNumbers>` it does not go down deeper to get the individual elements.

My fn to recurse thru the XMl

```
Protected Sub RecurseXML(nodes As XmlNodeList)
    For Each node As XmlNode In nodes
        If (node.ChildNodes.Count > 1) Then
            RecurseXML(node.ChildNodes)
        Else
            node.InnerText = ChangeNodeValue()
        End If
    Next
End Sub
```

Basically, trying to read entire XML and change certain vlues[node names not known] and then save the update document.

Comment: Can you post your existing code?

Comment: I treid, SO tells me I have too much code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your code doesn't go into `<TelephoneNumbers>` because of line

```
If (node.ChildNodes.Count > 1) Then
```

There's only one child element here so it stops at that level.

Comment: any recommendation to get around it?

Comment: Change `(node.ChildNodes.Count > 1)` to `(node.ChildNodes.Count > 0)`.

Comment: Doing that the recursion breaks out from the first node and does not go through the rest of the doc.

Comment: Why? The first node has children.